# Optimality condition inspired by subdifferential of square root: $y\in \text{argmin}(g(x)-a^Tx ) \Rightarrow y\in \text{argmin}(g^2(x)-2g(y)a^Tx).$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, variational-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$ be a proper convex lower semicontinuous function. Suppose that $f$ is bounded by below, and for simplicity that $\inf f = 0$. Set $\varphi:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$ as $\varphi(x):=\sqrt{f(x)}$. It is known that
\begin{align*}
 \partial\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}\partial f(x)\quad \text{for all $x\in\text{dom }\partial f$ with $f(x)\neq 0$.} 
\end{align*}
In particular, this implies that, if $\xi\in\partial\varphi(x)$, then $2\sqrt{f(x)}\,\xi\in\partial f(x)$ for all $\xi\in \mathbb R^d$ and $x\in\text{dom }\partial f$ with $f(x)\neq 0$. This can be rephrased as
\begin{align}\label{pty}
 \text{If $x$ is a minimizer of $\sqrt{f} - \xi$, then it is a minimizer of $f-\big(2\sqrt{f(x)}\big)\xi$.}
\end{align}
The question is whether this is true for nonconvex functions, say for an $f$ which is only proper and lower semicontinuous.

I have tried the following. If we take a minimizer $x$ of $\sqrt{f}-\xi$, then for $s\in\mathbb R^d$,
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{f(x)}-\xi x\le \sqrt{f(s)}-\xi s\quad\text{and hence } \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{f(s)}\le  \xi(x-s).
\end{equation}
If we multiply both sides by $\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(s)}$, we get
\begin{align}
 f(x) - f(s) \le \big(\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{f(s)} \big)\xi(x-s)\quad\forall s\in\mathbb R^d.
\end{align}
For $s\in\mathbb R^d$ with $f(s)\le f(x)$, it is easy to see that $\xi(x-s)\ge0$ and hence that
\begin{align}
 f(x) - f(s) \le \big(2\sqrt{f(x)}\big)\xi(x-s), \quad\text{that is}\quad f(x) - \big(2\sqrt{f(x)}\big)\xi x\le f(s) - \big(2\sqrt{f(x)}\big)\xi s.
\end{align}
For $s$ with $f(s)\ge f(x)$, it seems not so easy to conlude the same. In this case, recalling that $\sqrt{f(x)}-\xi x\le \sqrt{f(s)}-\xi s$, multiplying on both sides by $\sqrt{f(x)}$ leads to
\begin{align}
 f(x) - (\sqrt{f(x)})\xi x \le \sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{f(s)} - \xi s\le f(s) - (\sqrt{f(x)})\xi s.
\end{align}
But the $2$ next to $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is missing. Here is where I see the main problem. Is there any reference for these type of questions?

Comment: Do you want to show that for any vector $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$:

$$\text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \left (\sqrt{f(x)}-\xi^T x \right)= \text{argmin}_{x \in\mathbb R^n} \left ( \sqrt{f(x)}\left (\sqrt{f(x)}-\xi^T x \right) \right)?$$

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: What does “proper” mean in this context?

Comment: @MartinR A function $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$ is proper if there exits $x\in \mathbb R^d$ such that $f(x)\neq +\infty$.

Comment: @Alberto: OK, thank you for the clarification. – And how do you define the subdifferential for functions which are not convex?

Comment: @MartinR As the limiting one. The chain rule appearing in the post, on the left hand considers the subdifferential in the limiting sense ($\varphi$ might not be convex), and on the right hand side the usual convex subdifferential.

There is an abuse of interpretation, when the statements are rephrased. This is due to the fact the question is precisely if it is possible to make sense of this interpretation. 

The question: Is it true that
if $x$ is a minimizer of $\sqrt{f} - \xi$, then it is a minimizer of $f-\big(2\sqrt{f(x)}\big)\xi$.

Comment: @Amir What is to be proven is:
\begin{align}
x\in \text{argmin}_{y\in\mathbb R^d}\big(\sqrt{f(y)}-\xi^\top y\big)\quad \implies x\in \text{argmin}_{y\in\mathbb R^d}\big(f(y)-2\sqrt{f(x)}\,\xi^\top y\big).
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us prove the following statement for $g(x) \ge 0, x\in \text{dom } g$, which covers the one in the OP by setting $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$:

> If $y$ is a minimizer of $g(x)-a^Tx$, then $y$ is a minimizer of $g^2(x)-2g(y)a^Tx$, i.e., $$\color{blue}{y\in \text{argmin}\left(g(x)-a^Tx \right) \Rightarrow y\in \text{argmin}\left(g^2(x)-2g(y)a^Tx\right)}.$$

As $y$ is a minimizer of $g(x)-a^Tx$, then for any $x \in \text{dom } g $:

$$g(x)-g(y)\ge a^T(x-y) \tag{1}. $$

To prove that $y$ is a minimizer of $g^2(x)-2g(y)a^Tx$, we need to show that for any $x \in \text{dom } g $:

$$g^2(x)-2g(y)a^Tx \ge g^2(y)-2g(y)a^Ty \\ \equiv \color{blue}{(g(x)+g(y))(g(x)-g(y))\ge 2g(y)a^T(x-y)} \tag{2}. $$

- If $g(x) \ge g(y)$, then $g(x)+g(y)\ge 2g(y) \ge 0$ and the LHS of (1) is non-negative; thus, (2) follows by multiplying the two inequalities $g(x)+g(y)\ge 2g(y) \ge 0$ and (1).
- If $g(x) < g(y)$, then $0\le g(x)+g(y)< 2g(y)$ and both sides of (1) are negative, so (2) is obtained by multiplying the two inequalities $0\le g(x)+g(y)< 2g(y)$ and $0 \le g(y)-g(x)\le a^T(y-x)$.

This completes the proof.

---

Following the same method, the following extension can be proven for any $k \in \mathbb N$:

$$\color{blue}{y\in \text{argmin}\left(g(x)-a^Tx \right) \Rightarrow y\in \text{argmin}\left(g^k(x)-kg(y)^{k-1}a^Tx\right)}.$$

It is equivalent to show

$$\left (\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}g(x)^ig(y)^{k-i} \right )(g(x)-g(y))\ge kg(y)^{k-1}a^T(x-y). $$

---

The above can be further extended as follows for **any strictly increasing differentiable convex function** $\color{blue}{H: \mathbb R_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}}$:

$$\fbox{$\color{blue}{y\in \text{argmin}\left(g(x)-a^Tx \right) \Rightarrow y\in \text{argmin}\left(H(g(x))-H'(g(y))a^Tx\right)}$}.$$

Using a similar proof method, it is implied from the observation that for any fixed $y\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, the function

$$\frac{H(x)-H(y)}{x-y}$$

is non-negative and increasing in $x$ over both intervals $(0,y)$ and $(y,\infty)$ (note that for the convex function $H$ we have $H(y)-H(x)\ge H'(x)(y-x)$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$; the limit of the function is $H'(y)$ as $x \to y$).

---

The problem is special and interesting. The result can be used in a two-person **Stackelberg game** where the cost functions of the leader and follower are $g(x_L)-a^Tx_L$ and $g^2(x_F)-2g(x_L)a^Tx_F$, respectively. Here, we proved that any point $(y,y)$ with $y \in \text{argmin} (g(x)-a^Tx)$ is a pure-strategy equilibrium of the game.

Comment: Great, it seems correct. It seems the question was no so complicated as I thought. By the way, thank you for the game theoretical interpretation.

Comment: Do you think this can be easily generalized, say, to something like
\begin{align}
 y\in\text{argmin}(g(x) - a^\top x)\quad\implies\quad y\in \text{argmin}(g^k(x)-kg^{k-1}(y)a^\top x),
\end{align}
where $k\ge1$.

Comment: @Alberto I tried to simplify the problem and look at it in a different way. You made a special and nice observation. Yes I think so and did some calculations (not finalized yet).  I just added the extended one for $k \in \mathbb N$, but I think it should be hold for any $k \ge 1$.

Comment: I see. Me too. Though I doubt it can hold in a very general case, say, 
\begin{align}
 y\in\text{argmin}(g(x) - a^\top x)\quad\implies\quad  y\in\text{argmin}(\varphi(g(x)) - \varphi'(g(y))a^\top x),
\end{align}
where $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a general differentiable function. Maybe if it  satisfies properties like: increasing, nonnegative. I wonder whether this is interesting for Stackelberg games. However, this generalization is much beyond than my original doubt.

Comment: @Alberto please check the general case just added.

Comment: I did some calculations, and it seems correct! Nice! This is definitely much more than I expected.